How to find the names of strings used in scripting, like the Bounding Box?
I'm tired of encountering errors due to incorrect node names. In this case, I want to create a Bounding Box node in Blender 4.1 using Python, but I can't seem to find the correct name. To avoid wasting time with incorrect names, I need to know all the available nodes and their names.
    #bbox_node_type = 'GeometryNodeBoundingBox' FAILED 
    #bbox_node_type = 'NodeBoundingBox' FAILED 
    #bbox_node_type = 'BoundingBox' FAILED 
    #bbox_node_type = 'Bounding Box' FAILED

I can't find any documentation of a list of this type anywhere, so I tried programmatically yet I also failed miserably.
def list_all_node_types():
    # Create a temporary node tree
    temp_node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups.new(type='GeometryNodeTree', name='TempNodeTree')
    
    # List available node types by creating dummy nodes
    node_types = set()
    for node_type in bpy.types.Node.bl_rna.properties['node_type'].enum_items:
        try:
            # Create a dummy node to check if the type exists
            temp_node_tree.nodes.new(type=node_type.identifier)
            node_types.add(node_type.identifier)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error with node type '{node_type.identifier}': {e}")

    # Print the list of node types
    print("Available node types:")
    for node_type in node_types:
        print(node_type)

    # Cleanup: Remove the temporary node tree
    bpy.data.node_groups.remove(temp_node_tree)

list_all_node_types()

Im tryin something like this, but is not working
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\addons\chef_master.py", line 44, in <module>
    list_all_node_types()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\addons\chef_master.py", line 23, in list_all_node_types
    temp_node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups.new(type='GeometryNodeTree', name='TempNodeTree')
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: '_RestrictData' object has no attribute 'node_groups'


If you are asking questions about python/scripting, please use the according tags on your question - some people here filter questions by tags. And I have removed the geometry tag, because its for questions about creating, generating or editing an object's geometry, not specifically Geometry Nodes.

Seems a duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/249911/98738

When you add a node in UI, you can see a new line in the Info window:

It is easy to get node type from ops operator. As you see, the name is 'GeometryNodeBoundBox'

Not the answer that I was looking for...yet even better to be honest. XD. Thank you very much.


Click the node (to activate it)
⬆ ShiftF4
paste this code (you can use macro software to autotype it…): C.area.type='NODE_EDITOR'; C.window_manager.clipboard=str(type(C.active_node))[18:-2]
↩ Enter

and the type is now in your clipboard.
